# Get Type From If Condition

Tags: c#, .net

Below is the code In which I am not getting what System Type it contains as my If Condition is resulting True
Can you Please help me in showing System Type In message box if my condition results true

```
 public static System.Type[] trackedRevisionsElements = new System.Type[] {
    typeof(CellDeletion),
    typeof(CellInsertion),
    typeof(CellMerge),
    typeof(CustomXmlDelRangeEnd),
    typeof(CustomXmlDelRangeStart),
    typeof(CustomXmlInsRangeEnd),
    typeof(CustomXmlInsRangeStart),
    typeof(Deleted),
    typeof(DeletedFieldCode),
    typeof(DeletedMathControl),
    typeof(DeletedRun),
    typeof(DeletedText),
    typeof(Inserted),
    typeof(InsertedMathControl),
    typeof(InsertedMathControl),
    typeof(InsertedRun),
    typeof(MoveFrom),
    typeof(MoveFromRangeEnd),
    typeof(MoveFromRangeStart),
    typeof(MoveTo),
    typeof(MoveToRangeEnd),
    typeof(MoveToRangeStart),
    typeof(MoveToRun),
    typeof(NumberingChange),
    typeof(ParagraphMarkRunPropertiesChange),
    typeof(ParagraphPropertiesChange),
    typeof(RunPropertiesChange),
    typeof(SectionPropertiesChange),
    typeof(TableCellPropertiesChange),
    typeof(TableGridChange),
    typeof(TablePropertiesChange),
    typeof(TablePropertyExceptionsChange),
    typeof(TableRowPropertiesChange),
};

    public static  bool PartHasTrackedRevisions(OpenXmlPart part)
    {
           //Check Whether part.Rootelment contains System Type or Not
            if (part.RootElement.Descendants()
            .Any(e => trackedRevisionsElements.Contains(e.GetType())))
        {
         //If True Show e.GetType In Message Box
        }
        return part.RootElement.Descendants()
            .Any(e => trackedRevisionsElements.Contains(e.GetType()));
    }
```

Comment: I dont find any message box here? what actually you want to do

Comment: This code is uncommented and uncomplete. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As you can see If condition In my code is checking whether contains System Type or not I want to get System Type on which If Condition results true in messageBox

Comment: Edited question with comments

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, there may be changes for getting one more matches in the comparison, since you are comparing each item of one collection with every items in the other collection. So Hope that you are looking for something like this:

```
public static  bool PartHasTrackedRevisions(OpenXmlPart part)
{
     bool isFound = false;
     var typesFound = part.RootElement.Descendants()
                                      .Where(e => trackedRevisionsElements.Contains(e.GetType())).ToList();
    foreach(System.Type foundType in typesFound)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(foundType .ToString());
        isFound  = true;
    }
    return isFound; 
}
```

Comment: var initialTextDescendants = part.RootElement.Descendants<DeletedText>(); Instead of Deleted Text I want to pass foundType but when I pass part.RootElement.Descendants<foundtype>(); it results error as  foundtype is variable but used like type

Comment: use `System.Type` instead for `var` in foreach, take a look into the updates

Comment: cannot convert DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement to System.Type as typesFOund is of type DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement

Answer (score 0):

You can try `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Any`

```
  Type result = part.RootElement
    .Descendants()
    .Select(e => e.GetType())
    .FirstOrDefault(e => trackedRevisionsElements.Contains(e));

  if (result != null) {   
    //TODO: Put the right message here
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
```